# use aggregate to return a zero if criteria are not met

Tags: r, aggregate

mydf looks like this;

```
id<-c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
type<-c("a","a","a","b","a","a","a","b")
total<-c(1.1,1.2,2.1,2.3,3.4,3.6,4.2,4.3)
mydf<-data.frame(id,type,total)
```

I'd like to use aggregate to sum the totals of type=b, but to produce a df that has all id numbers.  so rather that using

```
mydf.ag<-aggregate(total~id, sum, data=mydf)
```

I'd like to use something like

```
mydf.ag<-aggregate(total~id, sum, data=mydf[mydf$type=="b",])
```

But this only returns a df with instance of type=b. Ideally I want mydf.ag to include zeros for id's 1 and 3.  so mydf.ag should look like

```
mydf.ag<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4), total=c(0,2.3,0,4.3))
```

Using aggregate would be ideal, but any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: `aggregate+merge` might be needed. `merge(data.frame(id=unique(mydf$id)),aggregate(total~id, sum, data=mydf[mydf$type=='b',]), all=TRUE)` and change the NA to 0 later

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, list(total=sum(total[type=='b'])), id]
```

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf%>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(total=sum(total[type=='b']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could first set `Total` equal to zero for where `type == "b"` and run your aggregate function

```
mydf[mydf$type != "b", "total"] <- 0
aggregate(total~id, sum, data=mydf)
```